# cCn I add API files to domain and use then from any where securely?

Tags: flutter

Let's say I have a Flutter app and a web app for the same project.

Can I add my API's files to a domain and then can I access them from my mobile app and web app? Also if I use MongoDB, then how can I connect it with API using that domain/hosting?

Or should I use AWS servers?

I am expecting detail guidance about whether I can add my API files to a domain and then I access them from my mobile app and web app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.